# Query to find records between two dates not working

Tags: mysql

I have a query that finds all records between the 1st of April and the 30th of April that looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `ar_videos` 
WHERE created
BETWEEN  '2013-04-01'
AND DATE_ADD(  '2013-04-01', INTERVAL 1 
MONTH )
```

Whenever I run the query it displays records from the month of May rather than April. What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Apart from the formatting of the WHERE clause is horrible?  Do you need to cast the string `'2013-04-01'` to an appropriate type? What is the type of the `created` column?

Comment: What column type is `created`? You might want to add a month and subtract a day to get the true "end" of April. That returns `2013-05-01`.

Comment: The `created` column is a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to fix your range:

```
created BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2013-04-01', INTERVAL 1  MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This finds things between `2013-04-01` and `2013-04-30`. Remember that `BETWEEN` is *up-to-and-including* the end of the range.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting exactly what you asked for:

```
mysql> select DATE_ADD('2013-04-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
+------------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD('2013-04-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) |
+------------------------------------------+
| 2013-05-01                               |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Remember that `between` is an inclusive comparison,

```
foo BETWEEN bar AND baz
```

is the same as

```
(bar <= foo) AND (foo <= baz)
```

If you want records for April only, you could try

```
WHERE (YEAR(datefield) = 2013) AND (MONTH(datefield) = 4)
```

or

```
WHERE (datefield >= '2014-04-01') AND (datefield < '2014-05-01')
                                                 ^--note, <, not <=
```

Comment: That's technically true but absolutely murderous on your database since that results in an automatic table scan.